# How to merge new files into another branch in TFS?

Tags: tfs

Ok, in TFS we have a main *trunk* branch and another branch, let's call it *secondary*.  We have created a new file in the *trunk* but when trying to merge that specific file, it does not give us the option to merge to the *secondary* branch.  We're assuming that it's because an analagous file does not exist in secondary.

Is this the cause of the problem and if so, how can we get that new file from the *trunk* into *secondary*?

Here, we are merging a file that does exist in *secondary*.  As you can see, the dropdown lists all three of our branches (*secondary* is actually the middle one):
[image]

Now, when I try to merge a file which was created in *trunk* after *secondary* was branched, *secondary* is no longer listed as a target branch.
[image]

Comment: Can you give us an example of the tf merge command you ran?  was is like this? : tf merge $/trunk $/secondary /recursive

Comment: The newly created file is already checked in?

Comment: Sorry, we're not TFS experts here.  We are interfacing with TFS through VS2010.  Through Team Explorer, we've located the file in the trunk we want to merge then right-click on it and select "Branching and Merging > Merge...".  So, I'm not sure what command that translates into.  By the way, we are trying to merge just this one specific file.

@PVitt: Yes, the new file is checked into the trunk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this should be possible over the VS GUI as follows: 
Select the folder where the new file was added and order a merge (of the whole folder) to your *secondary* branch.
Now all changed files of the folder appear in your pending list + your new file.
 Undo all other files & proceed with checking in only the one file that matters.

One could argue that this restriction of TFS in fact makes sense:

- If you 've made additional changes to the files you 're hereby protected from breaking your *secondary* branch.
- If you haven't made additional changes to any other files, it still makes sense to merge your, since the merge will only contain your new file.

Comment: I haven't tried that yet but to me it does make sense to want to be able to merge just one specific file.  Not all the time but there are certainly situations and it's up to the developer to figure out what merges may or may not break the build.

Comment: If you accuse TFS of 'protectionism' I absolutely agree with you, but that's just how it works.

Comment: I believe the reason behind this is that, if you're just "merging" the file in question, it isn't in any other branch, but when you're merging its parent (folder/branch), and that is, then a content change is to the folder which is in the other branch.

Comment: -1 Although this answer works it does not sufficiently explain why this occurs

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I could also make the argument that merge operations require a lot of attention and focus and I like to be in full control and be the one that decides what merges and what not. I personally think TFS is brain-dead and along with Visual Source Safe is living proof that Microsoft can't develop proper software.

Answer (score 11):

> trying to merge that specific file

To understand TFS it helps to remember that the unit of change is the **changeset**, and it is changesets (not files) that are checked-in and merged.

> We're assuming that it's because an analagous file does not exist in secondary

This is correct - at the version (changeset number) that the target branch is at, this file simply does not exist, so there is nothing to merge to.

In general, you don't gain anything by selecting a particular *file* in the merge source dialog - as it says, it asks you to select the source and targe *branches*. Specify the branches at their root, choose `Selected changesets only`, and TFS will show you a list of changesets that exist in source but have not been merged to target. If you only want the one that added this new file, you can select it in that list.

Comment: So when you select a specific file in Team Explorer and right-click select "Branching and Merging > Merge...", what exactly is it trying to merge if you are constrained to changesets?

Comment: I believe it would offer you all changesets that include that file. But I have only ever merged from the head of a hierarchy, so this ijust a guess.

Answer (score 6):

"Now, when I try to merge a file which was created in trunk after secondary was branched, secondary is no longer listed as a target branch."

For that, right click on the file in Source Control Explorer and choose Branch instead of Merge.  That will then bring up a dialog to specify the target.

Generally, you are better off merging trunk and secondary rather than pieces of it (easier to keep the branch consistent over time).

Comment: This seems to do the trick for me. Merging the parent directory as suggested in the accepted answer did not help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is just that you can't merge something that hasn't been branched. Notice if you merge the folder containing the new file, it says the action is [merge, branch] indicating you are branching the new file as the result of a merge of the parent folder. As far as I can tell, selecting the file > Merging & Branching > Branch, instead of Merge seems to be the solution. The only difference I see is the history then lists it has a [branch] rather than a [merge, branch]. After you've created a branch of the file in your *secondary* branch, you can merge changes to the file between branches.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use the [TF Merge command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy.aspx)